# Mongo, picking only first transaction for every hour in historic collection

Tags: mongodb, summarization, bigdata

My collection contains currency exchange rates over time. I wish to show a graph and I need to know only one value for every hour. However my data is much more dense, with one records every second or so.

How can I lower the density of records leaving only one per hour. I don't need average, any record from each hour would be sufficient.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52112613b45b5d057589009e"),
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-18T19:52:51.873Z"),
    "rate" : 0.00007382007912027975,
    "symbol" : "XAU=X"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52112613b45b5d057589009f"),
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-18T19:52:52.273Z"),
    "rate" : 0.00007382007912083746,
    "symbol" : "XAU=X"
}
```

Please take performance into consideration in your answer.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation framework, although if you really care about performance you should probably consider keeping historical record in a pre-aggregated collection.

If you can use record other than first per hour you can omit `$sort` phase and go straightforward to `$group`.

```
pipeline =  [
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "date" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "symbol" : "$symbol",
                "hour" : { "$hour" : "$date" },
                "day" : { "$dayOfMonth" : "$date" },
                "month" : { "$month" : "$date" },
                "year" : { "$year" : "$date" }
            },
            "rate" : { "$first" : "$rate" },
            "symbol" : { "$first" : "$symbol" },
            "date" : { "$first" : "$date" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "date" : 1,
            "symbol" : 1,
            "rate" : 1,
            "_id" : 0
        }
    }
]

db.foo.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of other options

1. Schema - Create and store a hourly summary document. When you add a new document update the "hourly" entry. This technique also works great if you want to sum, average etc. Also the overhead of maintaining this summary is amortized over all the operations.
2. Query - Run a query for the hour range based on the date field and limit(1) since you are ok with any row

The problem with the pipeline approach above is that the query is not optimized and will scan all documents in the collection. I would add a date range to the query to make it more efficient. Also the pipeline has a hard limit of 32MB. If you have more data than that the aggregation will not work.